# typo3 indexed search Is it possible to show access-restricted pages in typo3 to non-logged-in users?

Tags: search, typo3, indexed

i want to show results from access-restricted page to non-logged users also, possible with special class or text showing that if he registers he can get more content.

I found show.forbiddenRecords in typo3 property but its not working...

Im using typo3 4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even setting:
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.show.forbiddenRecords=1
config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = uid-of-login-page

indexed search does not search for forbidden records.

I found if i set in function execFinalQuery on line 1119 from:
$id_list[] = $this->cObj->getTreeList($rootId,9999,0,0,'','').$rootId;

to

$id_list[] = $this->cObj->getTreeList($rootId,9999,0,1,'','').$rootId;

that indexed search starts searching and showing forbidden records. I also posted this on bugs for typo3 hoping someone will check this as im no core user...

http://naprej.net

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = <id of login page>`?

Check the Typoscript reference.